# SFMC Dynamic Timezone Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, sql

Timezones are a concept I have a hard time wrapping my head around. I'm trying to build a dynamic timezone program that runs an adjusted sendtime on a daily basis.
Everyone should be receiving an email at the same time, let's say 3:30p.m. their time zone. I'm trying to adjust the send times so that they see an email at 3:30p.m. their time.

```
SELECT mailingstate,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AS sendtime,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'MOUNTAIN STANDARD TIME' AS mst_time,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'PACIFIC STANDARD TIME' AS pst_time,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'CENTRAL STANDARD TIME' AS cst_time,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'ATLANTIC STANDARD TIME' AS ast_time,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'NEWFOUNDLAND STANDARD TIME' AS nflst_time,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'EASTERN STANDARD TIME' AS est_time,
       SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDATE()), MONTH(GETUTCDATE()), DAY(GETUTCDATE()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'CANADA CENTRAL STANDARD TIME' AS ccst_time
FROM timezones_canada
```

The table timezones_canada is just a list of all the provinces/territories (field Mailing State) in Canada and is used to make the query execute. I intend on using this query as a subquery and not neccessarily a query activity that saves the output to a data extension.

I used smalldatetimefromparts to create a dynamic date time value on a daily basis. The results I get show what time it is in that timezone when it is 7:30 p.m. UTC.

| Mailing State | Adjusted Send Time |
| --- | --- |
| Alberta | 1:00 P.M. |
| British Columbia | 12:30 P.M. |
| Newfoundland and Labrador | 5:00 P.M. |
| Ontario | 3:30 P.M. |

What I actually want is what the time will be when it is 3:30 P.M. in each timezone- I'm using my timezone EST as reference

| Mailing State | Adjusted Send Time |
| --- | --- |
| Alberta | 5:30 P.M. |
| British Columbia | 6:30 P.M. |
| Newfoundland and Labrador | 2:00 P.M. |
| Ontario | 3:30 P.M. |

Comment: Can you update your question to include the rows in `timesones_canada`?

Comment: I updated the Q to clarify that timezones_canada table only contains a list of all the Mailingstates. I intend on using this query as a subquery to extract time data from, and not neccessarily to output to a data extension

Comment: What about daylight savings time?  Do you intend to account for that variable?

Comment: I would like to, but my first priority right now is getting the times to output correctly before I move to figuring out the daylist savings time as well

Comment: Updated my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where you calculate the UTC version of a specific date/time and then subtract the offsets for the Canada timezones.  The offsets would be different when it's daylight savings time.

```sql
SELECT 
  t.mailingState
, v.specificUTCDateTime
, case 
    when t.mailingState = 'AB' then dateadd(hh, v.mstUTCOffset, v.specificUTCDateTime)
  end adjSendDate
from timezones_canada t
outer apply (
  select
     SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDate()), MONTH(GETUTCDate()), DAY(GETUTCDate()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' specificUTCDateTime
    , -8 pstUTCOffset
    , -7 mstUTCOffset
    , -6 cstUTCOffset
    , -5 estUTCOffset
    , -4 astUTCOffset
    , -3 nflstUTCOffset
) v
```

Output:

```
mailingState  specificUTCDateTime         adjSendDate
------------  --------------------------  --------------------------
AB            2021-07-15 19:30:00 +00:00  2021-07-15 12:30:00 +00:00
```

The `outer apply` with no `from` is just setting values that are available in the outer query.

**Update**

If the `AT TIME ZONE` [adjusts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/229407/68443) [for daylight savings](https://bertwagner.com/posts/at-time-zone-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-time-zones-and-daylight-savings-time/), then you can simplify it this way:

```sql
SELECT 
  t.mailingState
, v.specificUTCDateTime
, case 
    when t.mailingState = 'AB' then convert(datetime2, v.specificUTCDateTime at time zone 'MOUNTAIN STANDARD TIME')
    when t.mailingState = 'VC' then convert(datetime2, v.specificUTCDateTime at time zone 'PACIFIC STANDARD TIME')
  end adjSendDate
from timezones_canada t
outer apply (
  select
     SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETUTCDate()), MONTH(GETUTCDate()), DAY(GETUTCDate()), 19, 30) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' specificUTCDateTime
) v
```

Output:

```
mailingState  specificUTCDateTime         adjSendDate
------------  --------------------------  ---------------------------
AB            2021-07-15 19:30:00 +00:00  2021-07-15 13:30:00.0000000
VC            2021-07-15 19:30:00 +00:00  2021-07-15 12:30:00.0000000
```